# NSIS AccessControl::GrantOnFile permission failing

Tags: nsis, access-control

I am trying to create and set a directory with NSIS and the [accessControl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk:AccessControl_plug-in) like the following:

```
CreateDirectory "$APPDATA\${productName}"
; create fileResources directory
CreateDirectory "$APPDATA\${productName}\fileResources"
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$APPDATA\${productName}\fileResources" "Everyone" "FullAccess"
Pop $0 ; get "Marker" or error msg
StrCmp $0 "Marker" Continue
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "Error setting access control for $APPDATA\${productName}\fileResources: $0"
Pop $0 ; pop "Marker"
Continue:
    Pop $0
```

I am receiving the following on $0 [image: Response] what is that response?

I want to make a folder readable and writable by the installed program

Comment: Do you use correct plugin? Check Ansi or Unicode - if you use incorrect one the response charset is wrong (like chinese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are building a Unicode installer using NSIS v3 and that you put the wrong plugin in the plugins subdirectory, that is why the result [looks chinese](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953).

To install a plugin correctly you need to put the ANSI .dll in NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi and the Unicode .dll in NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode.